# Can't run Windows XP on vmWare due to SCSI issues

Tags: windows, windows-xp, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I'm did have a virtual machine that I did run on a VMware Server before. Now do I try to get it up and runing on a VMware ESXi, but I keep geting following error message:

> There is at last one virtual SCSI device installed on this Windows XP
>   virtual machine. Windows XP does not include drivers for the BusLogic
>   SCSI adapter that VMware ESX uses for virtual SCSI devices. To use
>   these virtual SCSI devices, install the VMware driver in the virtual
>   machine.

and the console remains black.

If I try to folow the instractions on http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2007603 and change to BusLogic Parallel I get folowing error message and the console still remains black

> There us at least one virtual SCSI device installed on this Windows XP
>   virtual machine. Windows XP does not include drivers for the LSILogic
>   SCSI adapter that VMware ESX uses for virtual SCSI devices. To use
>   these virtual SCSI device, download the LSI Logic drivers separately.

Comment: How did you transfer the VM? I just stepped through the instructions at the [VMWare knowledge base article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2007603) you linked, and the solutions/options they provide should work.

Comment: When I scrapped the computer containing VMware Server, I copied all VM's to a USB drive. Then I have used VMware vCenter Converter Standalone to move the VM's I need to ESXi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you what to do;

> To use these virtual SCSI devices, install the VMware driver in the
>   virtual machine.

So install the VMWare vmtools inside the VM like it says, then it'll have the SCSI drivers needed to make this work.

Comment: How can I do that if I can't start the VM?
I have try to let VMware vCenter Converter Standalone install the VMware tool, but it dosn't change anything

Comment: You have to do it on the VMWare Server before moving it over?

Comment: Unfortunately the server does not remain :-(

Comment: ah... can you not rebuild it from scratch on the ESXi box?

Comment: It was originally built from an Acronis backup, but unfortunately, I do not remember if there has been any development on it since then.